# How to change sorting arrow ascending and descending with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sorting my data from database with ascending and descending order, sorthing works correct
except for button/ arrow that I want it to be shown inside button with class .column-sort.
I want that button to show up arrow when the order is desc and sho down arrow when the order is asc
like this desc ">" and asc "<".
I tried with append like  $('#'+column_sort+'').append(arrowDir), but it append every time if it
is placed outside success/ done().
How can I make it work after insider button element on ajax success?

Html

```
  <table>
    <thead class="thead_result">
      <tr>
        <th class="td-amount"><button  class="column-sort" id="income" data-order="desc"></button>Income</th>
        <th class="td-amount"><button  class="column-sort" id="expense" data-order="desc"></button>Expense</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="result"></tbody>
  </table>
```

//js

```
  <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.column-sort', function(){
            let column_sort = $(this).attr('id');
            let order       = $(this).data('order');
            let arrowDir = '';
            if (order == 'desc') {   
                arrowDir = '<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>';
            }else{
               arrowDir  = '<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>';
            }

            let ajax = $.ajax({
                url : '/getDaily',
                method:'post',
                data: {column_sort: column_sort, order: order},
                dataType: 'JSON',
            });
            ajax.done(function(data){
                //trying to reset column-sort to have desc ar asc
                $('#'+column_sort+'').attr('data-order', data.order);
                $('#'+column_sort+'').html(arrowDir);
                // data.order value to change desc to asc or desc to asc
                let thead = `
                  <tr>
                    <th class="td-amount"><button  class="column-sort" id="income" data-order="${data.order}"></button>Income</th>
                    <th class="td-amount"><button  class="column-sort" id="expense" data-order="${data.order}"></button>Expense</th>
                  </tr>
                  `;
                let html = '';
                $.each(data.result, function(k, v){
                     //mydata
                });
                
                $('.thead_result').html(thead);
                $('.result').html(html);
            })
        })
  </script>
```

//controller

```
  public function getDaily(){
      $column_sort    = $this->request->getPost('column_sort');
      $order          = $this->request->getPost('order');

      if ($order == "desc") {
         $order = "asc";
      }else{
         $order = "desc";
      }

      foreach($this->model->getDaily() as $row){
        $output[] = [
             'income'      =>  $row->income,
             'expense'     =>  $row->expense,
        ];
      }

      return $this->response->setJSON([
        'result'          => $output,
        'order'           => $order,
      ]);
  }
```

Comment: You appear to be setting the arrow `$('#'+column_sort+'').html(arrowDir);`, then completely wiping out the HTML of the button you just altered to set the arrow `$('.thead_result').html(thead);`.

Comment: Ok, it means that it reset automatically when calling thead element. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Well, don't reset the thead, or set the arrow after resetting the thead.

Comment: Thank you very much It's working perfect now!